# Segmentation fault error singly linked lists C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, singly-linked-list

Why is this getting an error:

```
int main(){
    lista *head, *x;
    head = nullptr;
    const int len = 3;
    int y[len] = {13, 4, 32};
    for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        x = new lista;
        x -> val = y[i];
        x -> next = head;
        head = x;
    }
    lista *p = head;
    // Changing lines are the next ones
    while(p->next != nullptr){
        p = p->next;
    }
    delete p;
    p = nullptr;

    print_lista(head);
    return 0;
}
```

But this is not:

```
int main(){
    lista *head, *x;
    head = nullptr;
    const int len = 3;
    int y[len] = {13, 4, 32};
    for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        x = new lista;
        x -> val = y[i];
        x -> next = head;
        head = x;
    }
    lista *p = head;
    // Changing lines are the next ones
    while(p->next->next != nullptr){
        p = p->next;
    }
    delete p->next ;
    p->next = nullptr;

    print_lista(head);
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work also in this way

```
while(p->next != nullptr){
    p = p->next;
}
p = p->next;
delete p;
p = nullptr;
```

This is the given error:

> the monitored command dumped core
>
> Segmentation fault

Isn't that the same thing? In the first case p is the next value of the second last element, in the second one p is the next value of the third last element, so p->next should be the next value of the second last element.
This is the structure:

```
struct lista{
    int val;
    lista *next;
};
```

The error occurs in the 'delete...;' line

**EDIT for Ben Voigt**

Why? If I run a test like this:

```
lista *p = head;
while (p->next->next != nullptr){
    p = p->next;
}
cout << p->next;
lista *z = head;
while (z->next != nullptr){
    z = z->next;
}
cout << endl << z;
```

Both p and z are 0x5575909e3eb0, aren't them the same?

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: You don't need to assign pointers to null after deleting them unless you need to signal to other parts of your code that something has been removed. Additionally, in C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: Can you explain in words what the line `p = NULL;` does? What exactly does it change? (And what does it **not** change?)

Comment: Is good practice to set as NULL dangling pointers, don't look at it

Comment: "Good practice" is highly debatable here. Have you **run this inside a debugger**? What is the value of `p` when you `delete p`? Is this pointer something you expect it to be?

Comment: I tried removing it, it changes nothing

Comment: Doing `p->next->next` is extremely risky as well. Why are you looking ahead through two levels of indirection at once?

Comment: I'd like to concentrate about the difference of the two codes, the first doesn't work and I don't know why

Comment: @tadman: Because that's necessary in order to be able to find and modify the pointer to the item being deleted...

Comment: Thanks @BenVoigt , I would like to don't do it, but I don't manage to hadle it

Comment: @BenVoigt Doing double next without any validation that the first next isn't null is a problem.

Comment: @tadman: That's a valid concern, but not an argument to avoid double indirection.  The double indirection needs to be managed correctly, or else it will fail on a list of length zero or one.  But "remove the last item in the list" is non-sensical for a list of length zero, so it ought to check this condition and fail before even beginning to iterate.

Comment: @tadman we are sure of that because the list is declared there... I simplified the code to make it more readable for stack overflow users, in a function there would be an if

Comment: You say you have a list, I don't see one. I only see nodes. Where is your list class that manages your nodes and pointer initializations? You are missing out on the power of classes this way.

Comment: In this example the list is implemented as nodes structure, no OOP

Comment: You still miss out on a lot of C++, this kind of style of programming is much more likely to have bugs (just saying). Are you limited to this kind of coding by a teacher?

Comment: Yes, I am in the first year of computer science class, we still didn't make classes

Comment: If you want a singly linked list, `std::forward_list` is *right there* in the standard library.

Comment: Can you ask your teacher to read this [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines).  And to watch this movie (from a C++ conference in 2015!). [Stop teaching C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk).  There is a big gap between the C++ he teaches and the C++ that is (should be) used in practice.

Comment: Ahahahah, I would like to do that, we don't really like him, but there's nothing to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in the failing code, you're deallocating the last item in the list, without removing it from the list.  The result is a list containing a dangling pointer, so later operations that walk the list have undefined behavior.

The working code does detach it from the list.

---

To answer your thought experiment, let's make it even simpler.

```
std::cout << head << '\n';
lista* z = head;
std::cout << z << '\n';

z = nullptr;
// now how many items are in the list?
std::cout << head << '\n';
std::cout << z << '\n';

// are `head` and `z` really equivalent?
z = head;
head = nullptr;
// now how many items are in the list?
std::cout << head << '\n';
std::cout << z << '\n';
```

Comment: Why? If I run a test like this:
    lista *p = head;
    while (p->next->next != NULL){ p = p->next ;}
    cout << p->next;
    lista *z = head;
    while (z->next != NULL){ z = z->next ;}
    cout << endl << z;
Both p and z are 0x5575909e3eb0, aren't them the same?

Comment: This is not indentable in comments, I edit the question

Comment: Both `p` and `z` are copies of pointers to items in the list.  `p->next` actually is part of the list.  `p->next = nullptr;` detaches that object from the list.  `z = nullptr;` erases a copy without changing the list.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understood it now, I was acting like p and head were the same and not just pointing the same thing, but now another question comes up to me, if it just deletes a copy, why does it throw a fatal error? It should just not work

Comment: `p` is pointing to the real node in the list, so `delete p;`, which deallocates the thing `p` points to (i.e. `*p`), deallocates the real item not a copy.  `delete` isn't acting on the pointer variable `p`.

Comment: Thanks Ben, it's hard to look for answers to niche questions online without being taken for fools, fortunately there are helpful people like you in these forums